# I'm having a problem with target="_blank". It's not working for me

Tags: html, hyperlink, tabs

I'm working on my portfolio and i'm trying to have it where you click on a screenshot of a project and it opens in a new tab. When I click it says "image can't be loaded." What am I doing wrong? Here's what I have:

```
<div class="mix col-lg-4 col-md-6 digital">
  <a href="https://still-reaches-77451.herokuapp.com" target="_blank" class="portfolio item set-bg" data-setbg="img/portfolio/4.jpg">
    <div class="pi-inner">
      <h2>+ See Project</h2>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

I don't know where to put it to make it work. I'm a new dev and I'm still figuring things out.

Comment: I've just tested this on my laptop on a blank index.html page, and it appears to open fine.  Is img/portfolio/4.jpg present?

Comment: Yeah it's just a screenshot of the assignment. So you didn't get a message that says "image could not be loaded"?

Comment: No I didn't, mine opened up fine

Comment: Thanks. I don't know what to make of this. I'm clicking on it and getting nothing.